# Is there any notation to denote the solution of a particular equation?

Tags: notation

Let's say that I have an equation:

$$x + 2 = 7 + y$$

If I need the solution for $x$, I can solve it and then use $5 + y$. No problem there.

But say I have an abstract equation. For now I am using the following to denote the equation:

$$eq.A$$

And to express **its** $x$ solution somewhere else:

$$\textbf{S}(eq.A)_{x}$$

Is there any universal notation to express the abstract notion of equation and its solutions?

Comment: I have never seen such notation. I think that if you define your notation at the start of the paper there will be no problems.